# Android Opengl ES transparent a color on a texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a texture. It is JPEG file, with a red RGB(255,0,0) background. What is the best way, to load this texture(or show) where my RGB(255,0,0) colors be TRANSPARENT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well jpegs don't have a transparency channel (AFAIK) so the first thing to do is edit it in Paint.NET or whatever, use magic wand or similar to make your red pixels transparent, and save as a PNG.

At runtime you need to load the PNG from assets or resources into a `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` bitmap before converting to a texture.

Finally your `GLSurfaceView` view needs to explicitly request that it's translucent cos its opaque by default... here's what I do in my `GLSurfaceView`-derived constructor, before calling `setRenderer()`:

```
    // Make the surface transparent, which it isn't by default
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0); 
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```